# Forwarded packets don't include their original IP address

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I have a dedicated machine which has 2 VMs running.
Host A (Router):

```
eth0 192.0.2.8
eth1 10.0.0.1
```

and I have

```
Host B(Application Server)
eth0 10.0.0.2
```

My IPTables config is:

```
modprobe iptable_nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

and an example firewall forward I use would be

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d 192.0.2.8 --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.2:25565
```

in all of my logs for applications they say all requests are coming from my external IP 192.0.2.8

What can I do to make it so that packets show the original source address and not 192.0.2.8?

Comment: If you don't want NAT, why are you using NAT?

Comment: I have multiple VMs behind one IP address. What else would I do instead of NAT?

Comment: He's asking because what you're describing as a problem is actually the main purpose of source NAT:  To allow multiple hosts to share a public IP.  Do you have multiple public IPs assigned to your router?

Comment: I only have the 1 IP on my router. It would cost me quite a bit more to add another address so I'm trying to share the one address with multiple hosts. I want mutiple hosts to be able to share one public IP but if I have a web server running it shows all of the traffic coming from the external IP not the IP of the client.

Comment: Put the web server on the 10. net.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to remove the NAT and instead do port forwarding to proxy servers for each port that you are serving.

The proxy servers then send the requests to the appropriate servers for the domain specified in the request. For example, for port 80, set up Apache2 as a reverse proxy as explained [in this IBM article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/reqpro/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.reqpro.install_upgrade.doc/topics/rw_apache.html).

For email set up a relay host. For other services you will need to find appropriate proxies.

Comment: Not very useful as there are quote a few different applications which don't won't be supported by a proxy.

Comment: @JamieH: Can you list the applications?

Comment: Things like Minecraft, Game Servers and that kind of stuff. I already have Nginx proxying things like Web Servers.

Comment: @JamieH: Your OP NAT rule, implies that you have only one server per application. If that is the case, you can just use iptables to port forward directly to the appropriate server without using NAT or a proxy. If you have multiple Minecraft type servers, then your only option is to use both direct port forwarding and port separation on the client side. That is to tell the clients to connect to your external IP address but to use different ports depending on which server they want to use. In any event, In any event, I upvoted the question because a lot of sys admins at smaller orgs have same Q.